# How to plot 1D array using python to get 25th, 50th and 75th percentiles

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, visualization

Hello I have an array

`x = [9.904725629894529e-06, 1.2634955055546016e-05, 1.5201896530925296e-05, 2.9845547032891773e-05, 3.49247275153175e-05, 3.4970289561897516e-05, 4.780302697326988e-05, 4.802399416803382e-05, 4.810681639355607e-05, 4.843798524234444e-05, 4.859635737375356e-05, 5.9152505855308846e-05, 5.9193022025283426e-05, 5.9363908803788945e-05, 5.9468671679496765e-05, 6.630286952713504e-05, 7.005851512076333e-05, 7.014916627667844e-05, 8.021695248316973e-05, 8.989680645754561e-05, 9.008277265820652e-05, 9.028125350596383e-05, 9.037737618200481e-05, 9.04681728570722e-05, 9.083149052457884e-05, 0.00021005164308007807, 0.00021028853370808065, 0.00021039179409854114, 0.00021039319108240306, 0.00021107416250742972, 0.00021134318376425654, 0.00021135005226824433, 0.00021196113084442914, 0.00021199103503022343, 0.0002120915160048753, 0.0002126666222466156, 0.000213045728742145, 0.00021316968195606023, 0.00021321520034689456, 0.00021339277736842632, 0.00021368247689679265, 0.0002137374976882711, 0.00021400606783572584, 0.00021451167413033545, 0.00021501131413970143]`

I want to plot this in python to find 25th, 50th and 75th percentile value.

I used
`plt.plot(x) plt.show()`
But the distribution doesn't look in a way like we can distinguish the numbers.

Comment: Why would you expect such a plot to show you any info about percentiles? You might want to look into something like https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html for that kind of information...

Comment: Hi @Bart, I wanted to plot this just to check if the distribution is correct. Eg., if the plot is skewed then getting 25th, 50th and 75th percentiles does not makes sense. Do you have any info on how this can be does where we also get percentiles as per proper distribution.

Comment: `import seaborn as sns; sns.boxplot(x); sns.swarmplot(x)`?  The boxplot shows the percentiles, the swarmplot shows where the values are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy to get percentiles for data. This following is from the [documentation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-percentile-in-python/%5D) for percentile.

```
import numpy as np

# 1D array
arr = [20, 2, 7, 1, 34]
print("arr : ", arr)
print("50th percentile of arr : ",
      np.percentile(arr, 50))
print("25th percentile of arr : ",
      np.percentile(arr, 25))
print("75th percentile of arr : ",
      np.percentile(arr, 75))
```

Output:

```
arr :  [20, 2, 7, 1, 34]
50th percentile of arr :  7.0
25th percentile of arr :  2.0
75th percentile of arr :  20.0
```

to apply this to your code this should show you the percentiles nicely

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [
    9.904725629894529e-06,
    1.2634955055546016e-05,
    1.5201896530925296e-05,
    2.9845547032891773e-05,
    3.49247275153175e-05,
    3.4970289561897516e-05,
    4.780302697326988e-05,
    4.802399416803382e-05,
    4.810681639355607e-05,
    4.843798524234444e-05,
    4.859635737375356e-05,
    5.9152505855308846e-05,
    5.9193022025283426e-05,
    5.9363908803788945e-05,
    5.9468671679496765e-05,
    6.630286952713504e-05,
    7.005851512076333e-05,
    7.014916627667844e-05,
    8.021695248316973e-05,
    8.989680645754561e-05,
    9.008277265820652e-05,
    9.028125350596383e-05,
    9.037737618200481e-05,
    9.04681728570722e-05,
    9.083149052457884e-05,
    0.00021005164308007807,
    0.00021028853370808065,
    0.00021039179409854114,
    0.00021039319108240306,
    0.00021107416250742972,
    0.00021134318376425654,
    0.00021135005226824433,
    0.00021196113084442914,
    0.00021199103503022343,
    0.0002120915160048753,
    0.0002126666222466156,
    0.000213045728742145,
    0.00021316968195606023,
    0.00021321520034689456,
    0.00021339277736842632,
    0.00021368247689679265,
    0.0002137374976882711,
    0.00021400606783572584,
    0.00021451167413033545,
    0.00021501131413970143,
]

percentile_25 = np.percentile(x, 25)
percentile_50 = np.percentile(x, 50)
percentile_75 = np.percentile(x, 75)

plt.figure("plot1")
plt.plot(x)
plt.axhline(percentile_25, color="C1", label="25")
plt.axhline(percentile_50, color="C2", label="50")
plt.axhline(percentile_75, color="C3", label="75")
plt.legend(loc="best", title="percentiles")
plt.xlabel("x_axis_label")
plt.ylabel("y_axis_label")
plt.title("stack title")
plt.show()
```

output graph:

[image]